# Panolens.js Issue: Buttons are not working on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-cardboard, webvr

I tried adding "top widget buttons". To do that, I followed the following code snippet:

```
<div id="wrapper">
   <!-- all your pop-up divs here-->
</div>
```

I tested my web page on Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox, Microsoft Edge, and Internet Explorer; and it is working as expected.

However, when I tried opening it on my mobile phone, specifically Samsung Galaxy Note 9, the buttons do not work anymore.

Here is a link to my source code on codepen.io: https://codepen.io/ferdric-avpl/pen/oNjQOYK

Please check out the "Launch Map" button after opening the link.

Comment: Which buttons are we supposed to look at from the Codepen example you added?

Comment: The Launch Map button is the button you are supposed to look at from the Codepen link I added.

Answer (score 0):

This can be fixed by using jQuery. For example:

```
$("#button-launch-floor-plan").on("click touchstart", function() {
    ShowModal();
})
```

Cheers!